# HibernateTemplate not getting the object when called through TaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, web-services, hibernate, scheduled-tasks

I have a web service DocGenerationServiceImpl that inserts (for every format) a record in the table using DocRepository and object representing the record as DocFileDO.  In the for-loop, I can get the id of the record that was created in the table.  For each record, I will call the executor's execute method where DocGenTask will search for the record given the id.  However, for example, there are 3 formats, the DocGenTask is able to get only the last record.  The first 2 it cannot find.  Although it's using hibernateTemplate.  Can please advise?

```
@RestfulService
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/docs")
public class DocGenerationServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private DocRepository docRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/generate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String generatedDocFile(DOCParam param) {

        for(String format : param.getFormatList()) {
                DocFileDO docFileDO = new DocFileDO();
                ...
                docRepository.saveDocFile(docFileDO);
                log.debug("docFileDO id = " + docFileDO.getId());

                DocGenTask task = new DocGenTask(docFileDO.getId());
                task.setDocRepository(docRepository);
                taskExecutor.execute(task);
        }
    }
}


@Repository
public class DocRepository {
    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public DocFileDO saveDocFile(DocFileDO docFile) {
        hibernateTemplate.save(docFile);
        hibernateTemplate.flush();
        return docFile;
    }
    public DocFileDO getDocFile(Long docFileId) {
        return hibernateTemplate.get(DocFileDO.class, docFileId);
    }

}

public class DocGenTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        generate();
    }
    private void generate() {
        DocFileDO docFileObj = docRepository.getDocFile(docFileId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things

1. Don't use `HibernateTemplate` it should be considered deprecated as of Hibernate 3.0.1 (which was released somewhere in 2006). Use the `SessionFactory` directly and use the `getCurrentSession()` method to get a hibernate `Session` to operate on.
2. You don't have transactions setup (judging from the snippets), to work with a databse you need proper transaction setup.
3. Your controller is doing much, all of this should be inside a service.

The first refactor your repository

```
@Repository     
public class DocRepository {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sf;

    public DocFileDO saveDocFile(DocFileDO docFile) {
        Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(docFile);
        return docFile;
    }
    public DocFileDO getDocFile(Long docFileId) {
        return sf.getCurrentSession().get(DocFileDO.class, docFileId);
    }

}
```

Now your code will probably fail due to improper transaction setup. Add `@Transactional` to all the methods (or class) that need a transaction (like the `saveDocFile` method).

As mentioned you probably should move the code found in the controller to a service. The controller should be nothing more then a thin integration layer converting from the web to an internal representation of something and then kick off a service/business method somewhere. This service-/business-method is also your transactional unit-of-work it either all succeeds or all fails.